# Spring boot custom dynamic message translations

Tags: spring-boot

What I want:
I have a database with different translations that can be modified from my page and should be loaded it to memory upon every edit, as well as a few static default values located in properties files.

As far as I understood it spring boot and thymeleaf use a MessageSource, not only are there (as my IDE sais) two, but also do they only load the static properties files.

Any ideas upon how I can do this? Maybe overwrite the bean? But if I do can I change that bean on runtime?

Comment: How did you define your MessageSource? And if you name it "messageSource" it willl override the default

Comment: I didn't define it yet. I am still kinda unsure if e.g. thymeleaf uses it.